# is it possible to automate test cases with email that requires 2FA?

Tags: selenium, automation

I am automating test cases and later our company change the email authentication with 2fa... I am now stack on how I can access the email with automation. Also, as far as I know Robot framework does refresh cache when executing that is why I cannot use cache. I am using Robot-Selenium framework.

Here's my code:

```
credentials = ServiceAccount(username=self.__username, 
      password=self.__password)
config = Configuration(server=self.__mailserver, credentials=credentials)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address=self.__smtp, config=config,
                          autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)
filtered_items = 
      account.inbox.all().order_by('datetime_received').filter( 
      sender__iexact=sender_email)
```

Comment: did u asked dev team if they have any specific API which can return 2FA code, then u can call API to get the 2FA token ?

Comment: What mail service are you using in your company?

Comment: Here is an example for google 2fa - if you have the secure key, will not be hard to adapt it. https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/selenium-testing---how-to-sign-in-to-two-factor-authentication-2joi

Comment: In general you don't want to verify emails, etc. using automation. There's no guarantee that they will be sent quickly so that you can process them. I would suggest you do functional testing of the site then have separate tests that verify that the automated mails system is working.